# Não consigo acessar o valor

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bom, estou fazendo um projeto para calcular IMC, com html, css (bootstrap) e javascript.

O problema é que não consigo acessar os valores que os usuários digitam no input, sempre que dou um "alert" aparece tudo em branco, ou NaN quando eu tento passar .value

Meu objetivo é acessar o valor numérico dos dois input para poder fazer o cálculo do IMC.

```js
/* As constantes */
const parsepeso = document.getElementById("peso");
const parsealtura = document.getElementById("altura");
const pegarBotao = document.getElementById("botao");

/* As variáveis */
var pegarPeso = parsepeso.value;
var pegarAltura = parsealtura.value;

/* Função principal que fará o código */
function main() {
    pegarBotao.addEventListener("click", function () {
        alert(pegarPeso);
    });
}

main();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap:400,600');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=ZCOOL+QingKe+HuangYou');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coiny');

.corpo{
    background-color: #5eeaa9;
}


#telaprincipal{
    background-color: #95afc0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 650px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    border-radius: 3%;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: greenyellow;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#telaprincipal input{
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
}

#telaprincipal label{
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    font-family: 'ZCOOL QingKe HuangYou', cursive;
    font-size: 32px;
    

}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Coiny', cursive;
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding-top: 23px;

}

#botao{
    margin-left: 305px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
}

#logo h2{
    margin-left: 290px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom: 85px;
    color: white;
}

#logo{
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#logo h3{
    margin-left: 320px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>IMC Calculator</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body class="corpo">
    <div id="telaprincipal">
        <div id="logo">
            <h1>Imc Calculator</h1>
            <h2>Seu IMC é:</h2>
            <h3 id="result">doodgk</h3>

        </div>

        <label>Digite o seu peso</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="peso" id="peso" placeholder="Peso (kg)">
        <label>Digite a sua altura</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="altura" id="altura" placeholder="Altura (cm)">
        <button id="botao" class="btn btn-success">Calcular</button>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você esta tentado pegar um valor que não esta definido ainda, as suas variáveis devem ser definidas assim que o usuário clica no botão:

```
/* As variáveis (Por enquanto o usuário não definiu os valores ainda) */
 var pegarPeso = null, pegarAltura = null;


/* Função principal que fará o código */
function main() {

    pegarBotao.addEventListener("click", function () {
        //Agora sim...
        pegarPeso = parsepeso.value;
        pegarAltura = parsealtura.value;
        alert(pegarPeso);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function main() {
    pegarBotao.addEventListener("click", function () {
          alert(parsepeso.value / Math.pow(parsealtura.value,2));
    });
}
```

ou se vc quer criar as variáveis

```
var pegarPeso;
var pegarAltura;

function main() {
    pegarBotao.addEventListener("click", function () {
      pegarPeso = parsepeso.value;
      pegarAltura= parsealtura.value;
      alert(pegarPeso  / Math.pow(pegarAltura,2));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece é que quando você cria a variável `pegarPeso` o valor do input será uma string vazia `''`, você não precisa criar essa variável, apenas a constante com a referência para o elemento HTML, quando precisar dela pega a propriedade `value` da constante

```js
/* As constantes */
const parsepeso = document.getElementById("peso");
const parsealtura = document.getElementById("altura");
const pegarBotao = document.getElementById("botao");

/* As variáveis */
var pegarPeso = parsepeso.value;
var pegarAltura = parsealtura.value;

/* Função principal que fará o código */
function main() {
    pegarBotao.addEventListener("click", function () {
        //Aqui os valores estarão em branco
        console.log(pegarPeso);
        console.log(pegarAltura);

        //Mas se pegar a propriedade value da constante, ai sim terá o que deseja
        console.log(parsepeso.value);
        console.log(parsealtura.value);
    });
}

main();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap:400,600');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=ZCOOL+QingKe+HuangYou');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coiny');

.corpo{
    background-color: #5eeaa9;
}

#telaprincipal{
    background-color: #95afc0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 650px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    border-radius: 3%;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: greenyellow;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#telaprincipal input{
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
}

#telaprincipal label{
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    font-family: 'ZCOOL QingKe HuangYou', cursive;
    font-size: 32px;
    

}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Coiny', cursive;
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding-top: 23px;

}

#botao{
    margin-left: 305px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
}

#logo h2{
    margin-left: 290px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom: 85px;
    color: white;
}

#logo{
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#logo h3{
    margin-left: 320px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>IMC Calculator</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body class="corpo">
    <div id="telaprincipal">
        <div id="logo">
            <h1>Imc Calculator</h1>
            <h2>Seu IMC é:</h2>
            <h3 id="result">doodgk</h3>
        </div>

        <label>Digite o seu peso</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="peso" id="peso" placeholder="Peso (kg)">
        <label>Digite a sua altura</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" name="altura" id="altura" placeholder="Altura (cm)">
        <button id="botao" class="btn btn-success">Calcular</button>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ... ***o valor do input será uma string vazia*** ... O valor do elemento ? ou o valor de `pegarPeso`?

Comment: @NoobSaibot o `document.getElementById("peso").value` estará vazio porque o usuário ainda não inseriu nenhum valor. Então ambos